# text-overflow: ellipsis not work on TextArea

Tags: html, css

I am using `<textarea>` to show multiple lines. And I want to use `"white-space:nowrap" and "text-overflow: ellipsis"` to constrain each line to be shown in one line with "..." at the end. Below is the css styles I set but the "ellipsis" is not working.

```
    display: block;
    width:400px;
    height:20px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

Is there a way to do that for  tag?

Comment: It works with me
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAC3FYHG4Q1F

Comment: I tried but 'text-overflow:ellipsis;' doesn't work in your demo. It should show '...' at the end of the line.

Comment: Iam using Firefox. It maybe browser compatibility.

Comment: What are you using as browser??

Comment: I am using chrome and safari

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @AshD sorry I ddin't find a solution to that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `white-space:pre` (*but it will only work with FF, as no other browser allows ellipsis on the textarea*)

```css
.no-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="no-wrap">
Nulla aliquet gravida nunc sit amet ultrices. Vestibulum ultricies mi eget feugiat aliquet
Curabitur placerat tellus vel pulvinar fringilla. Integer dignissim ut sem eget mollis.
Aliquam ac tortor in nunc dapibus blandit. Aliquam vehicula diam quis sem consequat
</textarea>
```

---

If you see the table at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values the only option that preserves new lines but does not wrap is the `pre`

Comment: I want to show '...' at the end of each line if that line extends out of the element width. But in your demo, I see 'white-space:pre' works but 'text-overflow:ellipsis' doesn't work.

Comment: Seems that only Firefox will allow ellipsis per line on the textarea. I changed my code to use a div since the `white-space:pre` will handle the multiple lines as well.

Comment: I really want to use <textarea> instead of <div>. Is there any way to support textarea in chrome, safari browsers?

Comment: @ZhaoYi if you see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow it mentions that the `text-overflow` property applies to `block container elements` which `textarea` is not. Unfortunately you will have to use something else or resort to scripts (*complicated*). What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have a project which is written by GWT. It uses TextArea to show some large document. I want to add a function to collapse the TextArea text by adding css style 'white-space' and 'text-overflow'. Unfortunately I couldn't make the 'ellipsis' working on TextArea. Since the project is built by GWT, I don't know how to add a <div> to wrap these text by GWT.

Comment: @ZhaoYi i see. I have no experience with GWT so i cannot offer any assistance with that..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Is there any way to make <textarea> to be block container element? Like add any css style on that?

Comment: @ZhaoYi i believe not. It can be a block element, but not a block container as it can contain just text and not elements.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found which works is to have a div showing for the ellipses, then on focus switch to a textarea (they are overlaying each other). You can do something with pure CSS:

```
<TEXTAREA>
<DIV>
```

DIV should sit on top (absolute) with `pointer-events: none`.

TEXTAREA has `opacity: 0`.

When you have `:focus` hide the DIV (`~` sibling) and change the TEXTAREA opacity to 1. You might find `:focus-within` pseudo selector to be handy too depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working for textarea in the table cell.I am using oj-textarea in the table cell which can have multiple lines. Tried below code, it shows ellipsis for that cells in the column irrespective of number of lines.

```
        [![<colgroup>
            <col width="100%" />
            <col width="0%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
        <td  class="module overflow"><textarea>hjkkh jam</textarea></td> <td style="width":100px;" class="module overflow">jamunao kjjhj jk \n     hj jh kjhjhj kj kkjhh jhjhjh hjj hkjh jhjh jhkj jh hhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjkhjk hjhjkhkhkjhkhkhjhjh</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
.module{
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.overflow {
  --max-lines: 2;
  width:100px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 2.4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 1rem; /* space for ellipsis */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.overflow::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "...";
/*   inset-block-end: 0;
  inset-inline-end: 0; */
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.overflow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
/*   inset-inline-end: 0; */

  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: white;
}
```

[image: In the image attached, even the cell has no String ellipsis is displayed]