# How to make text-overflow : ellipsis work on textarea in react.js + tailwind css

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, textarea, truncate, ellipsis

I have an issue as text-overflow: ellipsis doesnt work corectly in my project while using tailwind truncate on div with component which text content is wraped into `<textarea/>`. Text overflow is hidden but 3 dots are not shown.

Here is a simplified code snippet:

```
<div onClick={someFunction} className="relative inline-block max-w-24 h-6 truncate">
    <someComponent
      content={props.content} //this component is a read only textarea
    />
    <div className="absolute left-0 right-0 top-0 bottom-0"></div>
</div>
```

component code :

```
<textarea
    className="inline-block text-inherit bg-inherit max-w-full max-h-full"
    defaultValue={props.content}
    readOnly={true}
/>
```

I tried different display like `display : inline, inline-block, block, flex` etc. as wel as substitute tailwind truncate with `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;  white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Vhp6jQnyvh) this is not how a `<textarea>` wants to behave. This question has also been discussed here: [text-overflow: ellipsis not work on TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40921849/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-work-on-textarea)